# How do I add items from a store to a shopping cart using ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to make a web store application and in this case I am using video games as an example. I made a model class for a Video Game called `VideoGame.cs` which would be located in the `Models` folder of my ASP.NET MVC project. This class looks like:

```
namespace VideoGameStore.Models
{
    public class VideoGame
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }

    public class VideoGameDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<VideoGame> VideoGames { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I used EF Scaffolding to make a controller called `VideoGamesController.cs` located in the `Controllers` folder of my project. I thought of using this controller in such a way that an user with administrator role could add new, remove and update video games to this store. This is how my controller looks like:

```
namespace VideoGameStore.Controllers
{
    public class VideoGamesController : Controller
    {
        private VideoGameDBContext db = new VideoGameDBContext();

        // GET: VideoGames
        public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
        {
            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            ViewBag.TitleSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "title_desc" : "";
            ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

            if(searchString != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }

            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

            var videoGames = from v in db.VideoGames
                             select v;
            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                videoGames = videoGames.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString) || s.Description.Contains(searchString));
            }

            switch(sortOrder)
            {
                case "title_desc":
                    videoGames = videoGames.OrderByDescending(s => s.Title);
                    break;
                case "Date":
                    videoGames = videoGames.OrderBy(s => s.ReleaseDate);
                    break;
                case "date_desc":
                    videoGames = videoGames.OrderByDescending(s => s.ReleaseDate);
                    break;
                default:
                    videoGames = videoGames.OrderBy(s => s.Title);
                    break;
            }

            int pageSize = 20;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return View(videoGames.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }

        // GET: VideoGames/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            VideoGame videoGame = db.VideoGames.Find(id);
            if (videoGame == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(videoGame);
        }


        [Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
        // GET: VideoGames/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
        // POST: VideoGames/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Title,ReleaseDate,Genre,Description,Price")] VideoGame videoGame)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.VideoGames.Add(videoGame);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(videoGame);
        }

        [Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
        // GET: VideoGames/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            VideoGame videoGame = db.VideoGames.Find(id);
            if (videoGame == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(videoGame);
        }

        [Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
        // POST: VideoGames/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Title,ReleaseDate,Genre,Description,Price")] VideoGame videoGame)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(videoGame).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(videoGame);
        }

        [Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
        // GET: VideoGames/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            VideoGame videoGame = db.VideoGames.Find(id);
            if (videoGame == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(videoGame);
        }

        [Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
        // POST: VideoGames/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            VideoGame videoGame = db.VideoGames.Find(id);
            db.VideoGames.Remove(videoGame);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally I would be having a View in which the project would display the user a collection of videogames available in the store (and if the user would be an administrator, the collection could be managed on this view aswell). The view called `Index.cshtml` located in the `Views/VideoGames` folder would look like this:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<VideoGameStore.Models.VideoGame>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Video Games Store";
}

<h2>Video Games Store</h2>

@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        <p>
            @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
        </p>
    }
}

@using(Html.BeginForm("Index", "VideoGames", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>
        @Html.TextBox("searchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
}

<div class="row">
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)<br />
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)<br />
            &euro;@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)<br />
            @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                if(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                {
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) <text> | </text>
                }
            }
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id })
            @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                {
                    <text> | </text> @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
                }
            }
            <br />
            @Html.ActionLink("Add to cart", "AddToCart", new { controller = "ShoppingCart", id = item.Id })
        </div>
    }
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently I would like to add some code so that once a user clicks on the `@Html.ActionLink("Add to cart", "AddToCart", new { controller = "ShoppingCart", id = item.Id })` the user would be able to add the desired item to the shopping cart. I thought of adding a new controller called `ShoppingCartController.cs` to handle Shopping Cart processing and that is why I added it to the ActionLink HTML helper in the view. This is how the `ShoppingCartController.cs` looks like:

```
namespace VideoGameStore.Controllers
{
    public class ShoppingCartController : Controller
    {
        // GET: ShoppingCart
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }


        public ActionResult AddToCart(int Id)
        {
            //What code could I add here?
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

I have been reading that using session in MVC for making a shopping cart would not be an ideal way to solve this. Would I have to add a ShoppingCart model to my project and store the shopping cart data in a database (and if so, how could I make this look like)? I also read that I would not want a user to store data on a HTTP GET Request, but I would not want the user having to post their decision to add an item to the shopping cart on a different page over again. How could I adjust my `ShoppingCartController.cs`?

Comment: You use an AJAX `POST /ShoppingCart/AddToCart/1234` so the user doesn't navigate away from the current page. This action saves the shopping "session" to the database until checkout.

Comment: The [Music Store Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/) covers the basics